# inline AT&T asm syntax for using opcode directly instead of mnemonic

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

For unfortunate reasons I can't get into, I have to support an ancient assembler that doesn't have a mapping for a mnemonic I need.

I know the hardware supports it, but I can't seem to find any documentation online for how to use an opcode instead of a mnemonic.

Does anyone have a reference for how to do it in inline AT&T syntax on GCC.

Comment: e.g. `.byte 0x90` and such.

Comment: @Jester is the rest the same? Do the constraints still work the same way?

Comment: Oh you mean inline assembly. That's bad. You can still use constraints but probably only with fixed registers because you need to do the operand encoding yourself. What is the instruction you need? Consider using a separate function (possibly in a standalone asm file).

Comment: @Jester rdrand, and to support multiple versions of GCC and -fPIC, I'd rather not be picking the registers myself.

Comment: Luckily `rdrand` only takes a single argument and it is a register. As such you only need to cover a few cases if you want to allow the compiler to choose any register.

Comment: @Jester The single operand could also be a memory operand! Do you really want to deny the compiler this optimisation opportunity? ;-)

Comment: @fuz no, `rdrand` does **not** take a memory operand (at least the instruction set reference I have doesn't show it.) It's `r16`/`r32`/`r64`.

Comment: @Jester Indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily `rdrand` only takes a single argument and that is a register. As such you only need to cover a few cases if you want to allow the compiler to choose freely. Beware, it's still quite ugly :)

```
inline int rdrand()
{
    int result;
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        ".byte 0x0f, 0xc7\n\t"
        ".ifc %0, %%eax\n\t"
        ".byte 0xf0\n\t"
        ".else\n\t"
        ".ifc %0, %%ebx\n\t"
        ".byte 0xf3\n\t"
        ".else\n\t"
        ".ifc %0, %%ecx\n\t"
        ".byte 0xf1\n\t"
        ".else\n\t"
        ".ifc %0, %%edx\n\t"
        ".byte 0xf2\n\t"
        ".else\n\t"
        ".ifc %0, %%esi\n\t"
        ".byte 0xf6\n\t"
        ".else\n\t"
        ".ifc %0, %%edi\n\t"
        ".byte 0xf7\n\t"
        ".else\n\t"
        ".ifc %0, %%ebp\n\t"
        ".byte 0xf5\n\t"
        ".else\n\t"
        ".error \"uknown register\"\n\t"
        ".endif\n\t"
        ".endif\n\t"
        ".endif\n\t"
        ".endif\n\t"
        ".endif\n\t"
        ".endif\n\t"
        ".endif\n\t"
    : "=R" (result) : : "cc");

    // "=R" excludes r8d..r15d in 64-bit mode
    return result;
}
```

For 64-bit operand-size, you'll need a REX.W (0x48) prefix, but [the `"=R"` constraint](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html) instead of `"=r"` will avoid needing any other bits set in the REX prefix.

Note that `rdrand` also uses the carry flag the handling for which is left as an exercise for the reader.  gcc6 can use flag output operands, which is more efficient than `setcc`.

Comment: thanks, what about the instruction prefix, do I need something like:
0x48?

Comment: @JonathanHenson For a 64 bit rdrand, yes.  It's a bit more complicated than just using `0x48` because the compiler might chose to use a high register in which case you need `0x49` instead.  Jester's answer only works for 32 bit morde and needs to be reworked slightly for 64 bit mode.  You also need to change all the `.ifc` to use `%%rax`, etc.

Comment: Do you really have a 64 bit `gas` which doesn't understand `rdrand`?

Comment: As a simpler solution try `asm (".byte 0x48, 0x0f, 0xc7, 0xf0", "=a"(result) :: "cc")`.  This pins `result` to `rax` which might be slightly less efficient but is much easier to code.

Comment: @fuz yeah I recommended that but he doesn't want it :)

Comment: @Jester Maybe he does want it after being shown the ridiculous effort needed to let the compiler pick a register.  gas really needs a `.modrm` directive to just emit a set of operands so you can do stuff like that without getting insane.

Comment: @fuz I deleted a bunch of opcode asm with a snarky comment about how, if we're already requiring c99, what world does the assembler not have access to 'rdrand', and I changed it to something more managable.... well guess what.... I was wrong, got that ticket yesterday.

Comment: 64 bit also added 8 more general purpose registers you need to cover. Also the 32 bit registers are still available so depending on your use case (required output size) you might have more conditions to handle.

Comment: @fuz  as for the let the compiler pick discussion. It's because GCC is wildly inconsistent across versions and manually picking the registers is a number one source of build breakages for me.

Comment: @JonathanHenson I agree that there is a use case for supporting compilers that don't like `rdrand`.  But having such a large if-cascade just for this case is insane.  Why not add a configure test and pin the register to `rax` if the assembler doesn't support `rdrand` and use sane inline assembly otherwise?

Comment: @Jester in 64-bit mode, I can prolly get away with just specifying %r11 or something. That one should be safe.

Comment: @JonathanHenson You can use the `a` constraint to force `gcc` to pick `rax`. for you (so you don't need to add kludges).  That should definitely work.

Comment: @fuzz this is what I'm porting over:
"__asm__ __volatile__("rdrand %0;\n" "setc %1;\n": "=r"(output.u64), "=qm"(success)
                                :"r"(0)
                                :"cc");"

Comment: @JonathanHenson and Jester: use [`"=R"` to force gcc to pick a legacy (original 8) register](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html) that doesn't need a REX prefix.  (Or for a 64-bit operand-size, only REX.W will be required, not REX.B)  But it still gives the compiler flexibility in register allocation, unlike `"=a"`.  Also, if your compile is up to date (gcc6), you can use flag output operands from your asm to avoid the setcc, or an rdrand intrinsic.  (You only said your assembler was ancient, not the compiler.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I really wish I could tell you how screwed up the reason I have to do this is. Anyways, take it to say GCC 4.3.x is involved on some build servers somewhere that matter. Most of the time, this code is built with modern compilers, but there's still ancient crap folks have yet to upgrade.

Comment: @JonathanHenson: Yeah, I figured your compiler would be as crusty as your assembler :/  Other than C++ABI mismatch, you *should* at least in theory be able to use a new compiler to build binaries for an old distro, if you install a new compiler (maybe on a clone of the install in a VM.)  Using a compiler older than the HW it's running on is dumb (as I'm sure you know) because its tuning settings won't be updated for that microarchitecture, among other reasons.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've given up on prebuilt C++, not worth the headaches. I've gone to pure C99 with C89 header files if I build libraries, and use C++ only if I 100% control the environment, build from source is an option, or for application programming.

Comment: @JonathanHenson: You're all set, then.  A brand new gcc should in theory be able to build binaries that work on your ancient gcc4.3 distro using its libraries, if that's easier than porting code to work with obsolete compiler versions.  (Especially if there are any compiler bugs that affect your code.  But a new compiler could "miscompile" old headers if they have any UB, because of more aggressive / less forgiving optimizers).  I'm glad I don't have to use old gcc myself, neither option is very nice. :P

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
long result;
char success = 0; /* make sure we don't get surprised by setc only writing 8 bits */

/* "rdrand %%rax ; setc %b1" */
asm volatile (".byte 0x48, 0x0f, 0xc7, 0xf0; setc %b1" : "=a"(result), "=qm"(success) :: "cc");
```

The `a` constraint forces the compiler to use the `rax` register for `result`.  This is as general as it gets without being obnoxious.  I suggest you to add a configure test to check if the assembler understands `rdrand` and use this code:

```
long result;
char success = 0;

#ifdef HAVE_RDRAND
asm volatile ("rdrand %0; setc %b1" : "=r"(result), "=qm"(success) :: "cc");
#else
asm volatile (".byte 0x48, 0x0f, 0xc7, 0xf0; setc %b1" : "=a"(result), "=qm"(success) :: "cc");
#endif
```

While there might be a tiny performance penalty in forcing the compiler to use the `rax` register if the assembler does not understand `rdrand`, it is far outweighted by the complicated kludges needed to allow any register to be used.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing this:

for x86:
````
unsigned char success_high = 0, success_low = 0;
        __asm__ __volatile__(".byte 0x0f, 0xc7, 0xf0;\n" "setc %1;\n": "=a"(output.i386_fields.u_low), "=qm"(success_low)
                                 :"a"(0)
                                 :"cc");

            __asm__ __volatile__(".byte 0x0f, 0xc7, 0xf0;\n" "setc %1;\n": "=a"(output.i386_fields.u_high), "=qm"(success_high)
                                 :"a"(0)
                                 :"cc");
````

Comment: and for 64 bit:
__asm__ __volatile__(".byte 0x48, 0x0f, 0xc7, 0xf0;\n" "setc %1;\n": "=a"(output.u64), "=qm"(success)
            :"a"(0)
            :"cc");

Comment: I removed the clobers on a though, cause that didn't make any sense.

Comment: @JonathanHenson Why is the  phony `"a"` input operand there anyway?

Comment: @JonathanHenson That code looks sensible.  Make sure that the constraint on `%1` is `%b1` so gcc generates `cl` instead of `ecx`.  Just `%1` might lead to compilation failures if the compiler decides to keep `output.i386_fields.u_low` in a register.

Comment: @fuzz, thanks for jumping in on this. Jester's answer is a bit more exhaustive to the general topic. I ended up doing something similar as your suggestion. I'm grateful. I'm only marking his to provide some googlability to the problem for future unfortunates.

Comment: @JonathanHenson It's my pleasure.  Please let me know if you have any problems.

Answer (score 2):

As of [binutils 2.41](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/binutils/2023-July/128719.html), a new [directive `.insn`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dDirectives.html) permits the generation of arbitrary instructions.  While this may not help you and your old assembler in particular, it may be useful for future readers encountering this question.  For the example of `rdrand`, this could look as such:

```
#define rdrand(x) asm (".insn 0x0fc7/6, %0" : "=r"(x))
```

The `.insn` directive automatically figures out which encoding and instruction size to use based on the operand given, so we can use a macro like the above for all operand sizes, even if memory operands were present (though for `rdrand` these are not allowed of course). For example,

```
long long example(void)
{
    char foo;
    short bar;
    int baz;
    long long quux;

    rdrand(foo);
    rdrand(bar);
    rdrand(baz);
    rdrand(quux);

    return (foo + bar + baz + quux);
}
```

becomes

```
0000000000000000 <example>:
   0:   0f c7 f0                rdrand %eax
   3:   66 0f c7 f2             rdrand %dx
   7:   0f be c0                movsbl %al,%eax
   a:   0f bf d2                movswl %dx,%edx
   d:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
   f:   0f c7 f6                rdrand %esi
  12:   01 f0                   add    %esi,%eax
  14:   48 98                   cltq
  16:   48 0f c7 f1             rdrand %rcx
  1a:   48 01 c8                add    %rcx,%rax
  1d:   c3  

                ret
```

You can see how `.insn` is not able to tell apart 8-bit and 32-bit operands as the x86 instruction encoding realises 8-bit instructions with separate opcodes instead of a prefix.  This may lead to invalid results.  If desired, an assertion can be added to avoid this case:

```
#define rdrand(x) do { \
    _Static_assert(sizeof (x) > sizeof (char)); \
    asm (".insn 0x0fc7/6, %0" : "=r"(x)); \
    } while (0)
```