# How to print the register number with gcc-style inline assembly?

Tags: assembly, gcc, clang, inline-assembly, arm64

Inspired by [a recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71354223/417501).

One use case for gcc-style inline assembly is to encode instructions neither compiler nor assembler are aware of.  For example, I gave [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52191043/417501) for how to use the `rdrand` instruction on a toolchain too old to support it:

```
/* "rdrand %%rax ; setc %b1" */
asm volatile (".byte 0x48, 0x0f, 0xc7, 0xf0; setc %b1"
    : "=a"(result), "=qm"(success) :: "cc");
```

Unfortunately, hard-coding the instruction means that you also need to hard-code the registers used with it, greatly reducing the compiler's freedom to perform register allocation.

On some architectures (like RISC-V with its `.insn` directive) the assembler provides a way to systematically build original instructions, but that seems to be the exception.

A simple solution would be to have a way to obtain the undecorated number of the register to manually encode it into the instruction.  For example, suppose a template modifier `X` existed to print the number of the register chosen.  Then, the above example could be made more flexible as such:

```
/* "rdrand %0 ; setc %b1" */
asm volatile (".byte 0x48 | (%X0 >> 3), 0x0f, 0xc7, 0xf0 | (%X0 & 7); setc %b1"
    : "=r"(result), "=qm"(success) :: "cc");
```

Similarly, if there was a way to have gcc print `12` instead of `v12` for SIMD register 12 on ARM64, it would be possible to do stuff like this:

```
float32x4_t add3(float32x4_t a, float32x4_t b)
{
    float32x4_t c;

    /* fadd %0, %1, %2 */
    asm (".inst 0x4e20d40 + %X0 + (%X1<<5) + (%X2<<16)" : "=w"(c) : "w"(a), "w"(b));

    return c;
}
```

Is there a way to obtain the register number?  If no, what other options exist to encode instructions neither compiler nor assembler are aware of without having to hard-code register numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've actually had the same problem and came up with the following solution.

```c
#define REG_CONST(n) asm(".equ .L__reg_const__v" #n ", " #n);

REG_CONST(0)
REG_CONST(1)
REG_CONST(2)
REG_CONST(3)
// ... repeat this for all register numbers ...
REG_CONST(27)
REG_CONST(28)
REG_CONST(29)
REG_CONST(30)

float32x4_t add3(float32x4_t a, float32x4_t b) {
    float32x4_t c;
    // fadd %0, %1, %2
    asm(".inst 0x4e20d40 | .L__reg_const__%0 | (.L__reg_const__%1 << 5) + (.L__reg_const__%2 << 16)" : "=w"(c) : "w"(a), "w"(b));

    return c;
}
```

how does this work?

1. Keep in mind that the placeholder like `%0`, `%1`, ... will be filled with a register name through simple string replacements by the compiler *before* passing the result to the assembler.
2. inside assembly files we can use the `.equ` directive to define symbols to represent integers. (symbols that start with `.L` will be not be visible in the generated object file, so we don't unnecessarily clutter the symbol table)
3. each of the invocations of the `REG_CONST` macro will define a (local) symbol: `.L__reg_const__v0` which will be equal to 0, `.L__reg_const__v1` equal to 1, `.L__reg_const__v2` to 2, and so on.
4. the macros are intentionally placed at the top of the file, outside any function because the resulting `asm(".equ .L__reg_const__v0 0")` expression is supposed to go at the top of the assembly file.
5. in the `asm(".inst ...")` template inside the `add3` function the `%0`, `%1`, `%2` will then be replaced with whatever register the compiler selected for `a`, `b` and `c`.
6. since we sneakily wrote the placeholder without any space directly after the `.L__reg_const__` expression, the replacement will turn it into expressions like `.L__reg_const__v7`.
7. but this corresponds exactly to the name of the integer symbols we defined at the top! so the assembler will actually pick this up as a symbol and replace it with the integer value we defined.
8. after evaluating the symbols, the result is a purely numeric expression and the assembler will happily "or" the integer values together, yielding the desired opcode.

Comment: This is a nice hack, but it will only work on architectures/assembly dialects where register names are valid identifiers, right? I imagine `%rax` would break things...

Comment: @Siguza - Except he's not using the "register name" is he?  By running `%X0` right up against `.L__reg_const__`, he's making an identifier with the register name as the suffix on the symbol name.  Having a percent sign as part of the identifier might be problematical for x86, but I believe there's a [modifier](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86Operandmodifiers) (`V`) to turn that off.

Comment: That's a cool idea!