# How to inline assembly code using bits (hard code) in C?

Tags: c, inline-assembly, riscv, gem5

We can use inline assembly by using `__asm__()`. However, this approach can only support instructions that are recognized by the compiler.

What I am using is gem5 hardware simulator, in which I implemented a new instruction in RISCV. Such instruction is a bit string of 1's and 0's. Hence, if such instruction is in the executable, then it will be fetched, decoded and executed by gem5 hardware simulator.

However, since that is a new instruction, the compiler does not recognize it.

For example, suppose the instruction that I implemented has mnemonic `newInst %a0, %a1`. If I directly insert it using inline assembly by

```
__asm__("newInst %0, %1": /* etc... */);
```

The compiler would not be able to translate that into machine code.

Hence, may I know if there is a way to hard code the instruction using inline assembly, without modifying the compiler?

Comment: If you're using GCC, technically it's the assembler that would have to translate `newInst a0, a1` to machine code.  GCC inline asm is truly just text processing, substituting strings it generates from your constraints into the template at the `%[op]` "conversions", a lot like printf.  (clang, OTOH, defaults to using its built-in assembler, so it does actually parse your asm as it compiles.)  But I assume you mean without modifying GAS either, although GNU Binutils is a smaller project and probably much easier to modify and build from source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put raw bytes in with [`.byte`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Byte.html#Byte):

```c
__asm__ (".byte 0xf0, 0x0b, 0xaa");
```

Comment: Thanks! I think one potential problem of using raw bytes is the conflict of the registers being used. For instance, the instruction ```newInst %a0, %a1``` requires two registers, which could only be hard-coded using raw bytes. May I know if there is a way to avoid the conflicts of the registers? What if we specified a register that is being used by some other instructions?

Comment: @EthanL.: This answer is incomplete.  As always, you need to use Extended asm with `"=r"` and `"r"` constraints to tell the compiler about register operands.  And a `"memory"` clobber if your instruction reads or writes memory other than a `"m"` input.  If you have to hard-code register numbers by encoding manually with `.byte` or `.word`, you'll want `register int t1 asm("t1");` or whatever.  But much better if there's some pseudo-instruction that can take a numeric opcode and symbolic register names for an R-type instruction, so you could just use it normally with regs chosen by GCC.

Comment: You might also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71354999/2189500) SO question that talks about embedding register numbers in byte codes.